# Walking DOM break down

Tags: php, dom

I have this simple DOM walking function that I have used a few times.

This is a simplified version :

```php
function walk_DOM(&$dom, &$node, $func){

    $args = array(&$node, &$dom);

    call_user_func_array($func, $args);

    if ($node->nextSibling !== null) {
        walk_DOM($dom, $node->nextSibling, $func);
    }
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $children = nodeList_to_array($node->childNodes);
        walk_DOM($dom, $children[0], $func);
    }
}
```

I am starting to question it's value. I recently used a new function as the $func argument. It was intended to allow only '#text' nodes and 'p' nodes to render.

that function is :

```php
function strip_test(&$node, &$dom){

    if (($node->nodeName !== 'p') &&
            ($node->nodeName !== '#text') &&
            ($node->nodeName !== 'body')) {

        if ($node->parentNode !== null) {
            $parent = $node->parentNode;
            $parent->removeChild($node);
        }
    }
}
```

Walk_DOM() stops without viewing all of the nodes. The nodes that remain still exist in the DOM. They just were never evaluated.

So, on to the question. Is there something obviously wrong with this technique? If not, is there a good way to debug DOM issues?

I have traced which nodes walk_DOM() visits and have found no difference with the portion it does cover and the portion it stops before.

In previous uses I have found that. Though it is simple, it does not double examine any nodes and has previously covered the whole DOM.

**EDIT :**

Just to be clear, When I say 'stops without viewing' I mean that in a list of (arbitrary) 50 nodes that have 0 to 3 layers of children. This function will parse about 25% of them then stop. The last node that it parses is a direct descendant of the DOM body.

Both functions also throw no errors.

Comment: When you mean "stops without viewing all of the nodes", do you mean that at a deeper level of recursion, some nodes are left out? Or does the recursion stop in total.

Comment: Not wrong, but superfluous - objects are always (effectively) passed by reference, there is no need for the explicit references. I also note that you are iterating the first child of any given node (`$children[0]`) - shouldn't you be doing `foreach ($children as $child) { walk_DOM($dom, $child, $func); }`? In which case you can probably scrap the `nodeList_to_array` function because a `DOMNodeList` can be iterated directly.

Comment: foreach would result in nodes being viewed multiple times, but thank you for the by reference info.